# replace anchor text with jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to replace the text of a html anchor:

```
<a href="index.html" id="link1">Click to go home</a>
```

now i want to replace the text 'click to go home'

i've tried this:

```
alert($("link1").children(":first").val());
alert($("link1").children(":first").text());
alert($("link1").children(":first").html());
```

but it all gives me null or an empty string

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Try

```
$("#link1").text()
```

to access the text inside your element.  The # indicates you're searching by id.  You aren't looking for a child element, so you don't need children().  Instead you want to access the text inside the element your jQuery function returns.

Comment: Thanks. Feel relieved that i've got the answer, and very stupid... for trying all different statements but forgetting the #-sign....

Answer (score 65):

To reference an element by id, you need to use the `#` qualifier.

Try:

```
alert($("#link1").text());
```

To replace it, you could use:

```
$("#link1").text('New text');
```

The `.html()` function would work in this case too.

Answer (score 19):

```
$('#link1').text("Replacement text");
```

The `.text()` method drops the text you pass it into the element content. Unlike using `.html()`, `.text()` implicitly ignores any embedded HTML markup, so if you need to embed some inline `<span>`, `<i>`, or whatever other similar elements, use `.html()` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Try this, in case of id

```
$("#YourId").text('Your text');
```

OR this, in case of class

```
$(".YourClassName").text('Your text');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function liReplace(replacement) {
    $(".dropit-submenu li").each(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        t.html(t.html().replace(replacement, "*" + replacement + "*"));
        t.children(":first").html(t.children(":first").html().replace(replacement, "*" +` `replacement + "*"));
        t.children(":first").html(t.children(":first").html().replace(replacement + " ", ""));
        alert(t.children(":first").text());
    });
}
```

- First code find a title replace `t.html(t.html()`
- Second code a text replace `t.children(":first")`

**Sample** `<a title="alpc" href="#">alpc</a>`

Comment: While the code in your answer may work, you should strive to create an excellent answer which explains why and how it works.