# Grab innertext from an anchor serverside

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

How can I grab the `<a>` inner text?  Are there any HTML helpers for this to work serverside with ASP.NET webforms? (this is not an MVC app)

```
Method()
{
   string trackingNumber = Database.GetTrackingNumber();
   ExtractText(trackingNumber);
}

string GetTrackingNumber()
{
     return "<a href=\"#\">TextINeedToExtract</a>"
}

ExtractText(string someHtml)
{
    //need good way to get innerHtml for the <a>. HTML is not well formed.
}
```

**Update**
I am trying to avoid adding more package dependencies.   Can jquery be used serverside to handle this situation?

Comment: Also take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625865/replace-anchor-text-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlAgilityPack

It's available from NuGet Repository

Comment: +1 - Using NuGet is tempting, but my co-workers have not come on board with NuGet yet.