# Jquery append img and a

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I need to append the img inside an `<a>` tag. I have been hacking at this and no resolve, driving me crazy. If you can help that would be great. I am using jQuery 1.5

```
while condition{
    $("<img>").attr("src", thumb).appendTo("#images");
}
```

End result should be:

```
<a href="#"><img src="xxxxx"></a>
```

When I use prepend or appendto I get this result:

```
<div id="images src="xxxxxxx"><a></a> 
OR
<a href="#"></a><img src="xxxxx">
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Try using `$('<img src="' + thumb +'" />').appendTo('#images');` instead.

Comment: What are you using the while loop for?

Comment: can see see the full html pleas

Comment: How about `.text()` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625865/replace-anchor-text-with-jquery

Comment: What does your mark-up look like before it's manipulated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("#images").append($("<a>", 
{
    href: "#", 
    html: $("<img>", { src: thumb })
}));
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/Rxkxg/

Comment: Interesting short-hand, I wasn't aware you could pass an object as the second parameter and populate it.

Comment: ++ I agree with @Brad. I had no clue :)

Comment: As much rep as the two of you have and neither knew this?  I find that to be interesting.

Comment: @Levi jQuery evolves pretty fast. If you don't stop and look around once in a while, you could miss it.

Comment: This is sweet, thanks. Both @Brad and your gave me good insight.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('<a>') // create anchor first
  .attr('href','#') // set anchor HREF attribute
  .append( // inside it, append an image
    $('<img>') // new image
      .attr('src',thumb) // set image SRC attribute
  ) // end append
  .appendTo('#images') // add to image body
```

Almost on the right track...

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/9hmVf/)**

Comment: @Brad - Aren't you supposed to close the tag like `$("<a/>")` and `$("<img/>")` or is that just optional?

Comment: Thanks, and I like that site JS FIDDLE as well.

Comment: @Scott: optional, as the selector is really just seeing what tag it needs to `document.createElement`. @Tom: You're welcome. And yes, jsFiddle is a fantastic website. ;-)

Comment: @Brad - Interesting. I've seen people on SO say that it's needed.  I guess I could've tested it myself =D

Comment: @Tom if you like @Brads answer, let me tell you, you will love mine... or not

Comment: @Scott: If you look at the [jQuery Source](http://www.jquery.it/src/jquery-latest.js), right in the beginning you'll see `rsingleTag = /^<(\w+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>)?$/` for single-tag generation, which the regex exempts the `/` character anyways.